# building user profile page rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, user-profile

I am currently working on writing code to build a profile page for each user that signs into my application. However I have spent many hours and can't seem to figure this one out. Please excuse me for any lack of knowledge, I am rails beginner and still am learning.

Here is part of my User Model to build the initial profile page:

```
  has_one :profile

  after_create :build_profile

  def build_profile
    Profile.create(user: self)
  end
```

In my Profiles_controller.rb

```
before_action :find_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

def index
  @profile = Profile
end

def show
  @profile = Profile.find(profile_params)
end


def edit
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  @profile.update(profile_params)
end

private

def find_profile
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end

def profile_params
  params.permit(:profile).permit(:name, :summary, :birthday, :user_id)
end
```

Here is my edit.html.erb

```
 <%= simple_form_for @profile do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.date_select :birthday %>
  <%= f.text_field :summary %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Save', class: 'submit' %>
 <% end %>
```

Corresponding logs

```
Started GET "/profiles/28/edit" for ::1 at 2016-02-19 06:16:22 -0500
Processing by ProfilesController#edit as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"28"}
Profile Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE         "profiles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 28]]
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?      ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" = ?     LIMIT 1  [["id", "28"]]
Rendered profiles/_form.html.erb (21.4ms)
Rendered profiles/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (28.8ms)
Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (1.2ms)
Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (5.2ms)
Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 325ms (Views: 316.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)


 Started PATCH "/profiles/28" for ::1 at 2016-02-19 06:16:38 -0500
Processing by ProfilesController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"==", "profile"=>   {"name"=>"TEST", "birthday(1i)"=>"2016", "birthday(2i)"=>"2",    "birthday(3i)"=>"19", "summary"=>"TEST!!!"}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"28"}
Profile Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "   profiles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 28]]
User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
 CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" = ?   LIMIT 1  [["id", "28"]]
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, _method, authenticity_token, profile, commit, id
(0.2ms)  begin transaction
(0.3ms)  commit transaction
Rendered profiles/update.html.erb within layouts/application (1.4ms)
Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (1.2ms)
Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (7.2ms)
Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 343ms (Views: 323.9ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)
```

When I navigate to profiles/28/edit, I receive the appropriate form. However upon saving the form my database does not update with the attributes I provided. Any direction, help or hints would be appreciated. If any further information is needed let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post the log generated when trying to update?

Comment: Corresponding Logs would help to debug the issue

Comment: update is not the method you are looking for, http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class it is update_attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is with the unpermitted parameters as shown in the log.

```
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, _method, authenticity_token, profile, commit, id
```

The method at the bottom profile_params should be changed as,

```
def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:id,:name, :summary, :birthday, :user_id)
end
```

Thats it, done. :-)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I changed my method to update_attributes and also replaced permit with require. It now is working!!!

Comment: Even update_attributes is not required, rails knows that you can leave as update ,                                                                                                          and +1 for your way of representing the question, with full details.

Answer (score 0):

Try update_attributes method

```
def update
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
end
```

Comment: No luck, I really appreciate the tip though. If it helps when I type Profile.last in my console. It displays the attributes as nil except for id and user_id. Even after clicking save to update name, birthday and summary etc.

Comment: in your console, 
  profile = Profile.last
  profile.update_attributes(name: "some_name")

What you are getting? any error